# HP QTP 11: Script execution fails when running in Firefox, but Debug Viewer shows result of operation

Tags: vbscript, cross-browser, qtp

I'm trying to run our automation, written for IE, on Firefox 3.6 and facing those frustrating problem:
I have a code:

```
Set cellDataItems = Browser().Page().WebElement().Object.getElementsByTagName("div")
For i = 0 to cellDataItems.length -1 
    MsgBox (cellDataItems.item(i).innerHTML)
Next
```

When script goes to line with MsgBox if stops with error:

> TypeError: obj[FuncName] is undefined

Then I press debug, see that i=0. I added cellDataItems.item(i).innerHTML into debug viewer, it shows it's value (see below) without errors. Also, cellDataItems.item(i).textContent shows fine in Debug Viewer.

The value of cellDataItems.item(i).innerHTML when i=0 is:

```
<table class="x-grid3-row-table" style="width: 100px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-0 x-grid3-cell-first " style="width: 98px; text-align: left;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-0" unselectable="on"><div align="left">AUD/USD</div></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

So, why script fails with that error, but debug viewer shows it? 
Thank you!

**Update** In Firefox's Console I see more details:

> Error: obj[FuncName] is undefined Source File:
>   file:///C:/Program%20Files/HP/QuickTest%20Professional/Bin/Mozilla/Common/components/ScriptWrapperXPCOM.js
>   ->
>   file:///c:/program%20files/hp/quicktest%20professional/bin/JSFiles/mzDotObj.js
>   Line: 76

**update 2:**

```
MsgBox (eval(cellDataItems.item(i).innerHTML))
```

When I use eval - it works! Maybe is there a some way do debug code of QTP's extension for firefox?

**update 3:**
How is that possible: expression "colItem.className" has value "x-panel", but after I execute expression

```
sClassName = colItem.className
```

the value of sClassName is Empty: 
[image: line 570 was executed, but sclassName is still empty]

This works:
    sClassName = eval("colItem.className")

How this even possible?!!!!!! Or I'm getting crazy, or QTP 11 has a biiig defect inside!

Comment: This does indeed look like a defect in QTP 11 (more specifically in the patch for Firefox3.6 support). I would recommend opening a ticket with HP support.

Comment: Thank you for help! You may look at my investigations below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason and found workaround.

So, somewhere in associated library I has a code:

```
Set itemCol = windows.item(i) ' line 1
sClassName = itemCol.className ' line 2
```

And in another library I have an expression :

```
arrMyTradeInfo=GlobalDictionary.Item("gdTrades")
```

With this code during execution of line 1 QTP will give error:

> TypeError: obj[FuncName] is undefined
>   But if I change code to (notice "item" function name - it in lower-case now) - the line 1 will work!!!:

```
arrMyTradeInfo=GlobalDictionary.item("gdTrades")
```

But then it will not work in line 2 - see update 3 in the question itself - the value of sClassName will be empty, but itemCol.className could contain string. In another library I have a function (notice className parameter):

```
Function GetFirstObjectByClassName(byVal Parent, byVal className, byVal tag)
    Dim result
     result = getElementsByClassName(Parent, className, tag)
     If (UBound(result)<0) Then
        set GetFirstObjectByClassName = Nothing
    Else
        set GetFirstObjectByClassName = result (0)
    End If   
End Function
```

When I changed it name to something different (csName for example), line 2 is working!!!

```
Function GetFirstObjectByClassName(byVal Parent, byVal csName, byVal tag)
    Dim result
     result = getElementsByClassName(Parent ,csName, tag)
     If (UBound(result)<0) Then
        set GetFirstObjectByClassName = Nothing
    Else
        set GetFirstObjectByClassName = result (0)
    End If   
End Function
```

So, this is workaround. I can't explain it why is this happening, my guess is: VBScript is not strictly-typed. And in QTP they implemented something like "virtual functions calls" like in C++ and Java based on some kind of run-time type information, butfor DOM objects from Firefox there was some collision, they gathered RTTI in wrong way.

So, the main conclusion and concern: **only one wrong letter-case (Item instead of item) could broke your code, that work with firefox's dom and will give you many pleasant hours of debugging!** SO, be careful!

Will open ticket with HP support.