# Is there any way to inject own code into QTP's 11 Extension for Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, qtp, firefox3.6

I'm still fighting with [HP QTP 11: Script execution fails when running in Firefox, but Debug Viewer shows result of operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095746/hp-qtp-11-script-execution-fails-when-running-in-firefox-but-debug-viewer-shows)

By entry in Firefox Error Console I see what files are used to perform interactions by QTP:

> Error: obj[FuncName] is undefined Source File:
>   file:///C:/Program%20Files/HP/QuickTest%20Professional/Bin/Mozilla/Common/components/ScriptWrapperXPCOM.js
>   ->
>   file:///c:/program%20files/hp/quicktest%20professional/bin/JSFiles/mzDotObj.js
>   Line: 76

So, as a possible way to find solution why script execution fails, but debug viewer and using of "eval" function works, I want to put some debug points in those JS files and see what happening. I tried to put alerts into mzDotObj.js, but looks like Firefox don't see the changes (or ignores alerts?). I tried to restart firefox, to do hard-refresh (Ctrl+F5 and Ctrl+R). So, is there any way t debug those js files, that qtp uses to interact with firefox.

Thank you!

Comment: Your code example in your previous post looked as VBScript. Does Firefox support VBScript ?

Comment: This code executed in Quick Test Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox caches XPCOM compoments and JavaScript modules ("fastload"). You need to ensure that the cache is ignored when you make your changes. In current Firefox versions you run Firefox with the `-purgecaches` command line flag. In Firefox 3.x you need to add a boolean [`nglayout.debug.disable_xul_cache`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Nglayout.debug.disable_xul_cache) preference and set it to `true`.